# Listen to changes to a Firebase collection and all documents within

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm building an app that includes discussion threads. Each Thread has a subcollection of Replies, and each Reply has a map of Reactions like this. So each Thread's subcollection would look like this if JSONified:

```
{
  'replyDocument1': { 
    'authorName': 'Steve Dave', 
    'text': 'this is a reply', 
    'reactions': {'': ['userid1', 'userid2']}
  },
  ...
}
```

I'm trying to use a Stream/Sink set up to listen to changes in the Replies subcollection. ie: Rebuild the Replies ListView anytime someone adds a Reaction to any Reply in the subcollection.

This is what I've got so far. The models and RepliesApi class don't do anything exciting so I've left them out.

```
class RepliesBloc {
  final String threadId;
  RepliesApi _api;
  final _controller = StreamController<List<Reply>>.broadcast();
  Stream<List<Reply>> get stream =>
      _controller.stream.asBroadcastStream();
  StreamSink<List<Reply>> get sink => _controller.sink;

  RepliesBloc(this.threadId) {
    this._api = RepliesApi(this.threadId);
    this
        ._api
        .collectionReference
        .getDocuments()
        .asStream()
        .listen(_repliesUpdated);
    this._api.collectionReference.snapshots().listen(_repliesUpdated);
  }

  void _repliesUpdated(QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    List<Reply> replies = _api.fromQuerySnapshot(querySnapshot);
    this.sink.add(replies);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _controller.close();
  }
}
```

```
class ThreadReplyList extends StatefulWidget {
  ThreadReplyList(this.threadId, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
  final String threadId;

  @override
  _ThreadReplyListState createState() => _ThreadReplyListState();
}

class _ThreadReplyListState extends State<ThreadReplyList> {
  RepliesBloc _bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this._bloc = RepliesBloc(this.widget.threadId);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    dev.log('starting ThreadReplyList.build', name: "ThreadReplyList.build");

    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: this._bloc.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return ListView.separated(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ThreadReply(snapshot.data[index]);
            },
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return SizedBox.shrink();
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

This loads the initial data fine and if I change the collection, eg: add or remove a Reply, the ListView rebuilds. However if I modify a Reply, eg: update the `reactions` map on a single Reply, nothing happens.

I've seen solutions which add listeners to each document in a QuerySnapshot but it's unclear to me how to implement that here.

Comment: why you use `getDocuments().asStream()`? According to documentation it just turn a single fetch into a stream that ends after emitting the result once. May you try `.collectionReference.snapshots()`?

Comment: @LoL i tried `...collectionReference.snapshots().listen()` at first but then it only responds when a document is added or removed, it doesn't do the initial populate. i've also tried doing both (which is what you're seeing here)

Comment: It should also do the initial population. It is weird...